# mySQL IF statement in trigger error in Maria DB

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, mariadb

This code works fine in fiddle to create the trigger.
https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=1929

However, I have the exact same code on my phpMyaAmin SQL command, but on phpMyAdmin return this in the create trigger section.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON product_price
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF (NEW.product_id = 'P9999') 
    
    THEN SET NEW.product_id = 'name99', NEW.value_price = 999;
    END IF;
    
    IF (NEW.product_id = 'P7777') 
    THEN SET NEW.product_name = 'name77', NEW.value_price = 777;
    END IF;   
END;
```

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ‘’ at line 8

My phpMyAdmin Server version: 10.4.21-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Could anyone help, please?

Comment: Did you use `DELIMITER` when creating the trigger?

Comment: Paul T. is correct, this definitely looks like a delimiter problem. You need to either specify a delimiter in your SQL query or use the graphical tool ("Create new trigger" from the Triggers tab) which handles the delimiter for you.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's the problem. I directly put the code in Trigger Console instead of the SQL panel, and it work totally fine.